# asp:FileUpload.FileBytes example in MSDN confusing

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-upload

I was just going to use the FileUpload.FileBytes property but looking into the respective example in the MSDN library I'm confused about this part:

```
int fileLen;

// Get the length of the file.
fileLen = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

// Create a byte array to hold the contents of the file.
byte[] input = new byte[fileLen - 1];
input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

(from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx), I've omitted a few unimportant lines)

The `new` in this code looks for me like food for the garbage collector with no use. (Possibly big food if the file is large.) Why don't they simply write:

```
byte[] input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

I am too new to .NET and C# to be brave enough to declare this simply as superfluous or a bad written example. Does it have any purpose (perhaps a performance benefit or so)? (Also I don't understand why they subtract 1 from `fileLen`.)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that whoever wrote the sample was going to use their input array for FileUpload1.FileBytes.CopyTo(...) or something similar. I see no reason to create the byte array and then assign FileBytes to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code samples from MSDN do vary in quality, and this is a good example of a bad coding sample.

As you say, it is easier to simply write:

```
byte[] input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

And there is an error with the length of the byte array - no reason to subtract 1 from the posted length.

Comment: The linked example was from .NET 3.5. I just saw that in .NET 2.0 documentation is the same example but without the -1 error. Weird...
Anyway: Thanks! I'm happy that I wasn't wrong with my understanding. (As mainly being a C++ programmer I still can't stay relaxed when I see the `new` keyword.)